# Adding logger to Jenkins pipeline shared library class

Tags: class, logging, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared

Trying to add logger to myClass. I want to see it in Jenkins console without using of "script.echo".

```
class myClass implements Serializable {
    def _logger
    def script
    myClass(def script, Map config) {
        _logger = script.getContext(TaskListener.class).getLogger()
        this.script = script
        this.config = config // some data
        log 'Initializing myClass...'
    }

    @NonCPS
    private void log(message) {
        _logger.println(message)
    }
...

def someMethod(){
    ...
    script.sh(someScript)
    ...
}
}
```

With this code in Jenkins console I see:

```
Initializing myClass...                <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
[Pipeline] sh
[test-job] Running shell script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.macys.devops.utils.myClass._logger
    in object com.macys.devops.utils.myClass@54e9341c
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    ....
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@4c564ac6
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    ...
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@6b58d460
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.PrintStream
```

When I comment

> this.script = script:

logger works, but I can't execute DSL commands (e.g. script.sh).

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try to move  logger creation:

> ```
>    _logger = script.getContext(TaskListener.class).getLogger()
> ```

to log method:

`@NonCPS
    private void log(message) {
        script.getContext(TaskListener.class).getLogger().println(message)
    }`

Comment: Ok, I see that this works but given the logger is merely a print stream why not just use ```script.println(message)``` without a non cps block?  what does this approach provide over the simpler scenario?

Comment: @PeterKahn sometimes you need to print debug information from a longer `@NonCPS` method, and calling CPS steps like `echo` from `@NonCPS` method [is not supported](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+CPS+method+mismatches#PipelineCPSmethodmismatches-UseofPipelinestepsfrom@NonCPS)

Comment: Oh, I missed that you needed NonCPS - I try to avoid those designs to ensure parallel etc is simpler.